# iOS New app Do not showing up in TestFlight App

Tags: ios, testflight, review

I uploaded my app in the appstoreconnect.apple.com, but it does not show in Testflight.
[image]

Is it ok situation?
And is it required to have a "Review" state after every build upload?

Answer (score 1):

When setting up Testflight for external testers, Apple would like to review the build before you can submit it for testing.

> If you invite external testers, the build needs to be approved by Beta App Review before testing can begin.

Source: https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devdc42b26b8

Answer (score 1):

There are two paths:

- Build available for internal testers(AppStoreConnect users in your team). For this the processing takes up to one hour. All the builds you submit to TestFlight will be available for them.
- Build available for external testers(non AppStoreConnect users, any email can be used here, you can also create multiple groups). For this, the build needs to pass a short review from apple, this usually takes up to one day. You can chose which builds to be available to each group of external testers.

These durations may vary based on the period of the year eg. in December everything takes longer as many apps are submitted